# Frozen Android emulator due to audio problems?

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, ubuntu-10.10, pulseaudio

Today I installed the latest version of Eclipse, Android SDK and AVD plugin. But I have a tedious problem. When I want to quit the emulator (with the X button), the emulator freezes and I can't click anything there anymore. Obviously it has something to do with the sound, because when I execute "pulseaudio -k" in console, the emulator quits.
Due to this fact, I tried the following to let the emulator at least run properly:

In Preferences->Android->Launch -> Default Emulator option -> -noaudio

and

Run Configuration -> Android Application -> [Application] -> Target -> Addidtional Emulator Command Line Options -> -noaudio

But nothing helps. Emulator stays frozen. Actually I want audio to run, but switching it off doesn't work either. So what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this problem described here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17294

There is a workaround so that you can quit the emulator:
Set in your virtual devices "Audio Playback Support" and "Audio recording support" to "no".

Answer (score 1):

I replied on the issue, but just if interested:

you may need to disable audio output instead, this is not desirable for me, so just select alsa (or esd/oss) by setting environment variable
`QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa`

Looks like there is no way to specify audio drivers in hardware.ini so the best solution is going to sdk tools directory, rename emulator in emulator.real and make a shell script named emulator containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa
exec $(dirname $0)/emulator.real $*
```

then `chmod 755 emulator`